A way to bootstrap Docker environment when running Testcontainers tests?
I wonder if there is a way to bootstrap a Docker environment when running tests with @Testcontainers.
Right now when I run a test:
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
internal class MyTest() {
    @Container
    val mongoDBContainer = MongoDBContainer("mongo:latest")


and I don't have Docker Desktop enabled I get:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration


Also see Test Container test cases are failing due to "Could not find a valid Docker environment".  You need additional permissions to install Docker in almost every environment, which your normal unit-test setup probably won't have.  I might separate out true unit tests from integration tests that have complex external dependencies like Docker.

@DavidMaze I don't want to install it, just start

Testcontainers requires a container runtimes, such as Docker.
